# Change variables so that the following equation depends on one parameter only

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, change-of-variable

I've got the following differential equation:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=rx(k-x) \quad \quad x(0)=x_0$$
I have to perform several changes of parameters/variables so that instead of depending on $x, k, x_0$ the differential equation depends on one parameter only. I've tried
$$y=\frac{x}{k} \quad \quad \tau=rt$$
and this way my equation is (where $\dot{y}=\frac{dy}{d\tau}$):
$$\dot{y}=\frac{1}{k}y(1-y) \quad \quad y(0)=\frac{x_0}{k}$$
Here I still have two parameters $(k,x_0)$ and I should have only one. Can someone help me continue?

**Edit**: Just to clarify, my final equation should depend on one parameter and of course it will also depend on the variable

Comment: $x_0$ is supposed to be value of x at point $0$, it is not a variable. So what you got is correct.

Comment: @sirous I know, but $x_0$ is still a parameter and my final equation can only depend on one parameter (and of course, it will also depend on the variable)

Comment: You made a mistake the original ODE is a Bernoulli 's ODE then you have a linear ODE. A factor $y$ is missing it seems to me.

Comment: @HansLundmark nope, I still have the $x_0$ using the answer to the question you suggested, and I need to get rid of that

Comment: @Aryadeva yeah that was a typo, thanks

Comment: With variables as in that answer (and $f(t)=0$ since your $k$ is just a constant) you get $dp/dt=p(1-p)$, $p(0)=p_0$, which depends only on $p_0$.